# magento2 ordered product report showing blank while export CSV

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.3, magento2.2.4, magento-2.2.5

[image: Here I can show All orders in Grid]
[image: When I export CSV report showing blank data]

Is there any solution please share why order product Report is showing blank.

Comment: did you already check filters before click the export button ?

Comment: yes @mrfizh i check all filters and in grid showing all orders perfectly but on time export its showing blank

Comment: maybe you must check your log file, to see if there is something wrong on export process and then if you still found nothing I hope this link could help you : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10992

Comment: okay sure i will check and give update if any thing find and thank you @mrfizh for giving your time

Comment: it's all right, hope information from us can help you to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue with this pull request https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/12909

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/12909/commits/d597cd3cb12bcbb3f8b95ce78a3d7b826977dbdc here is direct link for verified petch and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

please do index:reindex and reports/report_statistics/index from this path and select  refresh life time statistics the do day wise report and then export all order is came.

Comment: not working still